# In Angular2, when using a IterableDiffers, why is changeDetector being passed in?

Tags: angular

I fully understand IterableDiffers; but I do wonder why I sometimes see sample code of IterableDiffers being passed the local component's change detector, and I wonder why, as it seems to work without it, but I am sure it's being passed for a reason.

as in:

```
set ngBookRepeatOf(items) {
    this.items = items;
    if (this.items && !this.differ) {
        this.differ = this.differs.find(items).create(this.changeDetector);
    }
}
```

as compared to being passed just a null.

Comment: The parameter to `.create()` is the parent differ. See also [IterableDiffers](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/IterableDiffers-class.html)

I can't tell you what effect that has though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `ChangeDetectorRef` parameter isn't used in the `DefaultIterableDifferFactory` constructor. The default implementation of the `IterableDifferFactory` that is returned by default by the `find` method.

So you can provide the change detector or null...

See the source code:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts#L20

Comment: offtopic: How can use DefaultIterableDifferFactory in my unit test?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827551/how-to-inject-iterablediffers-service-into-a-unit-test