# how to inject IterableDiffers "service" into a unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying add unit tests for this component located in https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox....
But I got an error because the component has a dependency with the type: "IterableDiffers"

```
export class DualListComponent implements DoCheck, OnChanges { ....
constructor(private differs: IterableDiffers) {} ...
```

My first try looks like on this way:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { DualListComponent } from './dual-list.component';

describe('DashboardHeroComponent when tested directly', () => {

    let comp: DualListComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DualListComponent>;
    let heroEl: DebugElement;

    // async beforeEach
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [DualListComponent],
            imports: [ TranslateModule.forRoot()]
        })
            .compileComponents(); // compile template and css
    }));

    // synchronous beforeEach
    beforeEach(() => {

        let srouce: Array < any > = [
            { key: 1, station: 'Antonito', state: 'CO' },
            { key: 2, station: 'Big Horn', state: 'NM' },
            { key: 3, station: 'Sublette', state: 'NM' },
            { key: 32, station: 'Eureka', state: 'CO' }
        ];
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DualListComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        heroEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.hero')); // find hero element

        comp.key = 'key';
        comp.display = 'station';
        comp.source = srouce;
        comp.destination = [];
        fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger initial data binding
    });

    it('should display hero name', () => {
        expect(comp.available.list.length).toEqual(4);
    });
});
```

And the error what I got after run ;"npm test" is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'diff' of undefined
```

the error message is not too clear itself but the reason is because try use the object "differs" what should be load in the constructor.

any idea how to add it in the test?

**update 1**
after follow the instructions from Tiep Phan and insert "IterableDiffers" as a provider ... I got the issue: "Can't resolve all parameters for IterableDiffers"...
 I can understand the error but don't know how to solve it...the error basically  is because the constructor of IterableDiffers class accept an array of type "IterableDifferFactory".

```
constructor(factories: IterableDifferFactory[]);
```

Comment: you need to set `destination` to an appropriate non-empty array. The dual-list component expects that as an input and does not check against it being null. Otherwise, you should expect to see this error in your test. The error occures at line 107 of `dual-list.component.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understant why you want to inject `IterableDiffers`. It works well.

Your error happens here

```
buildAvailable(source:Array<any>) : boolean {
    let sourceChanges = this.sourceDiffer.diff(source);
```

`this.sourceDiffer` is undefined. If you take a look at source code you can notice that `sourceDiffer` is initialized within `ngOnChanges`. So you need to call `ngOnChanges`

Look at this article https://medium.com/@christophkrautz/testing-ngonchanges-in-angular-components-bbb3b4650ee8

Here is example for your case:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DualListComponent);
comp = fixture.componentInstance;
heroEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.hero')); // find hero element
comp.key = 'key';
comp.display = 'station';
comp.source = srouce;
comp.destination = [];

comp.ngOnChanges({ // add this
    source: new SimpleChange(null, srouce, true)
});
```

See it in action in **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6IwACTDAYDq7WtAyRwUM?p=preview)**

Another way is using temporary component as described in article above.

Answer (score 2):

add your dependencies to NgModule declaration

```
import { IterableDiffers } from '@angular/core';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [DualListComponent],
        imports: [ TranslateModule.forRoot()],
        providers: [
            //other provider
            IterableDiffers
        ]
    })
        .compileComponents(); // compile template and css
}));
```

Comment: if you're using Angular 2, you could add fatory from this https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/910c0d9ee7e1f556f773e37e7385d5dd58ef79fd/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts

Comment: how Can use this DefaultIterableDifferFactory? how can i import it?

Comment: if you're using Angular 4, you can, but you can copy it to your own =)))

Comment: copy this file is not a option i think .. IterableChangeRecord, NgIterable and others are not exported members... ;(